# Karati Api - Validating date and time format

Tags: karate

response = {"startDateTime": "2018-10-25T00:00:00Z",
                    "endDateTime": "2019-10-25T00:00:00Z"}

How would I validate date and time for this? ^^

And match response = {startDateTime:**??**}

I'm QA and not a Java expert but will be OK if someone could give me an example or a regex example for this ^^

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care to read the documentation you can find examples: https://github.com/intuit/karate#java-interop

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52892797/143475