# Karate: Validate a specific date in JSON response

Tags: karate

I need to validate a JSON response (like below) and check whether ANY one of the items in the JSON array has today's date as createdDate.

"createdDate" is actually returned as a timestamp, but I dont have the actual value. The only thing I need to validate is today's date. Order of the items is also not guaranteed. I looked at javascript macros specified at https://intuit.github.io/karate/, but it does not have an example of what I am trying to do. Please let me know any suggestions.

```
{
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "...",
        "name": "...",
        "createDate": "03-30-2020:10:12:30"

      },
      {
        "id": "...",
        "name": "...",
        "createDate": "03-31-2020:10:12:30"
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, one possible solution:

```
* def sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy")
* def today = sdf.format(new java.util.Date())
* def list = $response..createDate
* def fun = function(x){ return x.startsWith(today) }
* def filtered = karate.filter(list, fun)
* assert filtered.size() != 0
```

For more ideas, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55938480/143475

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52892797/143475

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
    "id": "...",
    "name": "...",
    "createDate": "#regex <your regex string>"
 }
```

For example if the date is expected in yyyy-mm-dd format

```
 "createDate": "#regex \\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}"
```

Comment: Hi wherath! I know this might be obvious to you, but would you mind editing your answer and adding a few words of explanation?