# In Json array of strings, how can I match a part of string is present? Karate DSL

Tags: json, regex, validation, karate

---Edited the question to add solution---
**---Question---**
I have a Json array of strings as below.

How can I validate whether it contains today's date **2021-10-11** or the word **PROCESSING-1** as a sub string in it?
BTW, I am trying it with Karate DSL

```
[
  "TEST1019005-2021-10-19T18:19:41.271055Z-PROCESSING-2",
  "TEST1019005-2021-10-19T18:19:41.271055Z-PROCESSING-1",
  "TEST1019002-2021-10-19T14:50:16.810678Z-PROCESSING-2",
  "TEST1019002-2021-10-19T14:50:16.810678Z-PROCESSING-1",
  "TEST1019002-2021-10-19T14:50:16.810678Z-PROCESSING-0",
  "777777-2021-10-19T09:24:33.064845Z-PROCESSING-2",
  "777777-2021-10-19T08:23:10.213230Z-PROCESSING-1",
  "777777-2021-10-19T08:23:10.213230Z-PROCESSING-0",
  "TEST1018001-2021-10-18T16:31:32.643392Z-PROCESSING-0",
  "TEST1013001-2021-10-13T15:13:59.974540Z-PROCESSING-0",
  "777777-2021-10-13T14:17:45.727585Z-PROCESSING-2",
  "Test01-2021-10-11T20:20:05.968159Z-PROCESSING-1",
  "Test01-2021-10-11T20:20:05.968159Z-PROCESSING-0",
  "333333333-2021-10-11T20:11:26.474697Z-PROCESSING-0",
  "333333333-2021-10-08T21:43:28.251925Z-PROCESSING-0",
  "232623234-2021-10-08T21:27:04.363014Z-PROCESSING-0",
]
```

**----Solution---**
I could achieve by the following reg-ex.

```
* match myArray contains "#regex (?i).*" + '2021-11-08' + ".*"
```

**Here is the code if it helps someone :**

- def myArray =
  """
  [
  "Cust1019005-2021-10-27T18:19:41.271055Z-PROCESSING-2",
  "Cust1019005-2021-10-19T18:19:41.271055Z-PROCESSING-1",
  "Cust1013002-2021-10-13T15:23:57.510469Z-PROCESSING-2",
  "333333333-2021-10-08T21:43:28.251925Z-PROCESSING-0",
  ]
  """
- def query = '2021-11-08'
- match myArray contains "#regex (?i).*" + query + ".*"

Answer (score 0):

Here's part of the solution:

```
* def today = 
"""
function() {
  var Formatter = Java.type("java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter");
  var LocalDate = Java.type("java.time.LocalDate");  
  var dtf = Formatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
  return dtf.format(LocalDate.now());
}
"""
* match each response contains today()
```

The rest is up to you. Note that there is a `#regex` match option as well: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#fuzzy-matching

Also refer these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60945563/143475

Comment: I tried that route. But match each or match any were not finding the portion of the string.     match failed: CONTAINS_ANY
$ | actual does not contain expected | actual array does not contain any of the expected items (LIST:STRING)

    $[15] | not equal (STRING:STRING)
    '232623234-2021-10-08T21:27:04.363014Z-PROCESSING-0'
    '2021-10-21'

    $[14] | not equal (STRING:STRING)
    '333333333-2021-10-08T21:43:28.251925Z-PROCESSING-0'
    '2021-10-21'
.......

Comment: @Maaza works for me. follow this process please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Sample project created to demo the actual issue in : https://github.com/HelpingFriends/Karate_TryOuts.git
 and the issue started as : https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1810

Comment: @Maaza sorry, you seem to have ignored the use of `match each`. if what I commented as an answer does not help, please assume that karate does not support what you want and look for another tool

Comment: I could achieve by the following reg-ex.  
** '* match myArray contains "#regex (?i).*" + '2021-11-08' + ".*" ' **

Here is the code if it helps someone :  
    * def myArray =  
    """  
        [  
            "Cust1019005-2021-10-27T18:19:41.271055Z-PROCESSING-2",  
            "Cust1019005-2021-10-19T18:19:41.271055Z-PROCESSING-1",    
            "Cust1013002-2021-10-13T15:23:57.510469Z-",  
            "333333333-2021-10-08T21:43-0",   
        ]  
    """  
 * def query = '2021-11-08'  
    * match myArray contains "#regex (?i).*" + query + ".*"