# How to reduce the decimal length to upto two decimal places in karate framework

Tags: karate

Below function is returning the output is 8.110000000000001. I want the output only upto two decimal places. i.e) 8.11

- def array = [2.16,1.34,1.32,1.25,0.65,0.48,0.42,0.26,0.14,0.06,0.03,0]
- def result = 0
- def fun = function(x){ var temp = karate.get('result'); karate.set('result', temp + x )}
- karate.forEach(array, fun)
- print result

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, using the JS `Math.round()`.

```
* def response = [1.001, 1.011, 1.015]
* def rounded = response.map(x => x.toFixed(2) * 1)
* match rounded == [1.00, 1.01, 1.01]
```

But it may have some limitations. Just write a function to do the conversion once and use it. Note that you can use [Java interop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60945563/143475) if you want to make use of `BigDecimal` etc. You can find plenty of solutions on the net.