# Karate comparing 2 arrays of numbers

Tags: karate

I am getting one array from an API response and the second is a list of calculated values.
I would want to match both arrays but the values could be slightly different due to rounding, so I'd like to do something like this

```
Values of array 1 included between values of array 2 +- 0.1
ie array2[i] - 0.1 < array1[i] < array[2] + 0.1
```

Is there a way to do that with karate match without having to write a javascript method to do the compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there's no way without writing some (minimal) JS.

For an example, refer: [How to reduce the decimal length to upto two decimal places in karate framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72728542/143475)